# In-app Updates (How is the appupdate type determined?)

Tags: android

I have been reading about in-app updates.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Wanting to know how is AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE/AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE decided? For my app I would prefer to have Immediate. Is it something that you decide when you upload your apk to playstore or is it determined automatically?

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just in case if anyone is looking for an in-app update library.. Check out https://github.com/SanojPunchihewa/InAppUpdater

Comment: So did you found out how to specify an update as immediate or flexible..? I would like to do both immediate and flexible in the application. Is it done in Google playstore console..?

Comment: @AkhilSoman - you decide whether you need immediate or flexi update. Nothing to be done in playstore console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is up to you what type of update you want the users to see(Immediate or Flexible) according to your logic. In your case, just implement the Immediate part and you are good to go. Also, if you want to implement both flexible and immediate updates then you may have to build logic around the version code of your APK.

Hope this solves your issue.

***UPDATE***

The above solution was temporary, which could have been used to integrate the API during the initial release. As of now, it's fairly simple, since all the functionality is available.

Comment: Noted. Thanks! Much appreciate your gesture. By any chance have a sample code?